# voting system, relational db, sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, voting-system

I want to design voting system with two tables.

First table contains candidates' index and name.

The other one contains index, voter and candidate's index whom the voter support.

One voter can support multiple candidates.

I want a sql query that shows candidates' name with number of its supporters.

So the result looks like

John 12, Bob 8, David 3...

```
SELECT `name`, COUNT(table2.voter) AS `count` 
FROM `table1` 
LEFT JOIN `table2` 
   ON table1.idx = table2.support 
ORDER BY COUNT(table2.voter) DESC;
```

The above query gave only one row with total number of voter.

Can anyone give me any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT `name`, COUNT(table2.voter) AS `count` 
FROM `table1` 
LEFT JOIN `table2` ON table1.idx = table2.support
GROUP BY `name`
ORDER BY COUNT(table2.voter) DESC;
```

You were missing a `group by` and hence getting only the first result.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `GROUP BY` the non-aggregate column (`name`), otherwise the query will default to one group; the entire result set; and pick an arbitrary `name`:

```
   SELECT `name`, COUNT(table2.voter) AS `count` 
     FROM `table1` 
LEFT JOIN `table2` 
       ON table1.idx = table2.support
 GROUP BY `name` 
 ORDER BY count DESC;
```

You can use column aliases in an `ORDER BY`, so I have update this also

Comment: it also works but vkp answered first. anyway thanks!